# Merge JS/CSS files

Tags: magento2, optimization, merge-css

I'm trying to compress the code files on my magento 2 store. And so we wanted to use the Merge JS/CSS files in the magento 2 admin.

We are not programmers, and we would like to not have to contact programmes to fix any problems because of high cost.

So what i'm wondering is, how big is the chance that something goes wrong with the site when i merge the files? and if anything goes wrong, can i just Unmerge them and everything will be fine?

Comment: you can disable merge css and js using admin backend

Comment: give it a try on your stage site instead of production.

Comment: back up your magento files and your database - then do whatever you want to do.  If you cause problems then you can use your backup.  This is a given anyway. ALWAYS back up your database and files before you try anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Change deploy mode into a developer mode

**Terminal command**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Open admin panel and follow the below steps

> 1.Store->configuration->advanced -> developer

**Js minify and merge**

Set yes for below configuration under Javascript tab

- Merge JavaScript Files
- Enable JavaScript Bundling
- Minify JavaScript Files

**CSS minify and merge**

set yes for below configuration under CSS setting

- Merge CSS Files
- Minify CSS Files

after set deploy mode into prodcution

**Terminal command**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

**Revert**

If you want to revert minify and merge, Set no to above configuration and then change into production mode

**Terminal command**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to revert back that setting.

if admin not work, then go to **PHPMyAdmin**

and find entry into **core_config_data** like

select * from core_config_data where path like '%merge%';

and change entry to 0 and do cache flush then your store will revert back